# What things should I take care while designing the structure of the project?

Tags: c#

I think if I add a lot of class files to the project then the performance of the project will be slow. Am I thinking right?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: I can't see the affect by adding 2-4 class files in project. Actually i want to know about it, if it really affect the project load time then in future i will mind it and will avoid the same.

Comment: 2-4 class a files? Why don't you add them, and measure to see if there's any meaningful impact. Also, you know that GitHub is a thing, right? You can go and view *thousands* of open source projects, quite a few of which are in C#. If you want to see what other projects are doing, that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that C# is a compiled language, therefore, all those class files are already compiled and optimized into a single solution at runtime. There exists the possibility of adding too much, always, but I think most web API projects will not even come close to such a limit that will cause application slowdown.

Just a typical empty project created in Visual Studio 2019 will have over 20 class files already in it and loads at runtime rather quickly.

Comment: OP is talking about _"too many class files...`project loading time`"_  and _"I can't see the affect by adding `2-4 class files in project`"_  **not** _"compiled"_ or _"runtime"_.  In fact OP does not mention the word _"runtime"_ at all.   However I think your last paragraph is fine

Comment: This answer was based on the interpretation that "project loading time" refers to the time the executable created from the project takes to load into memory and begin its execution. If taken to mean "the time it takes Visual Studio to open the project", then my answer is: project loading is always slow in VS, but adding class files will not have a significant impact on the time it takes to load the project into the IDE.

Comment: Sure that sounds fine.  Why not add that to your answer above?  Also, your first paragraph is not entirely correct either.  C# is not _"compiled...into a single `solution` at runtime"_ - there is no _"solution"_ just a binary.  It's not entirely compiled either, Visual Studio compiles the source code to IL code and at runtime it is JIT'd to native code.  Depending on the app's startup dependencies, this JIT step can be significant bases on the number of IL-equivalent classes that need to be compiled.  So the net effect of the number of classes in your VS solution could impact runtime anyway

Comment: ....it may not be all of them, but it requires static-code analysis to determine which and runtime analysis to measure how long it takes your app to startup